# The restrictive relative clause structure containing "you think be"?

Tags: relative-clauses, restrictive-clauses, parenthesis

I have read [this article](https://academicguides.waldenu.edu/writingcenter/grammar/clauses) which explains in detail what relative clauses are, but I still cannot clear up the structure of the below sentence(from [here](https://www.linguee.com/english-french/translation/you+think+necessary.html)):

> I want to know what program, where, and when it's anticipated would
>   replace these programs and would develop the kinds of skills you think
>   are necessary.

I thought `you think` is a parenthesis that can be removed from the sentence, which applies to this sentence that can be found in the same source:

> Consult your doctor for any personal medical evaluation you think
>   necessary.

we obtain the reduced relative clause:

> Consult your doctor for any personal medical evaluation (that is) necessary.

But when it comes to the first example the rule doesn't hold up anymore.

> I want to know what program, where, and when it's anticipated would
>   replace these programs and would develop the kinds of skills are necessary.

We can see that the "are" is unnecessary here.

I don't know what role the "you think" plays in these two sentences, and when can I add it?

Comment: Your example context is for ***you think***, not ***you know***. Both are optional, effectively functioning as "adjectival" elements qualifying *skills which [you think / know] are necessary*. Semantically, ***know*** wouldn't normally make much sense here (unless the speaker is "reminding" the addressee of some "hard truths" he the addressee would rather ignore), whereas ***think*** would often imply the speaker himself doesn't actually agree with what the addressee thinks. Is that what you mean by "what role"?

Comment: ...note that ***what program, where, and when it's anticipated*** is syntactic garbage as a "subject" for ***would replace / would develop***. People say things like that in off-the-cuff speech, but it wouldn't be normally be acceptable in a *written* context.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking here.